# How to make a graph in javascript/jQuery without graph libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graph

So, I kinda need a little help... Is there a way to make a line graph in javascript or jQuery without using any libraries? It doesn't matter if it doesn't look good but it should still be acceptable. If anyone knows about this, please do post a reply.

Thanx,
ProBroRLZ

P.S: If you need to know more info, just ask for it and I will reply.
:)

Comment: There's literally no reason to do this unless 1.) You refuse to pay for licensing or 2.) You're building a graphing product as a core business competency (unlikely, give your post) or 3.) You're doing homework. highcharts.com. It's a whole business even.

Comment: "Web design competitions." Either you can build products the best way possible or you're tying your hands for no reason. Your time is better spent learning any of the various charting libraries than doing "web design competitions."

Comment: I don't know if you've heard of the World Skills Competition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! I found an answer! Thanks to @keewnn for all the help by pointing me towards the svg link. This is a really basic, dynamic graph that is incredibly simple.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <svg height="150" width="150" style="border:1px solid black;">

    <!-- This is the background lines -->
    <polyline
    points="30,0 30,201 60,201 60,-1 90,-1 90,201 120,201 120,-1 150,-1 150,201"
    stroke="grey"
    stroke-width="1"
    fill="none" />

    <!-- This is the chart data -->
    
    <polyline stroke-linejoin="round"
    points="0,105 30,100 60,80 90,75 120,60 150,69"
    stroke="black"
    stroke-width="5"
    fill="none"
    stroke-opacity="1"
    stroke-linecap="round" />

  </svg>

</body>

</html>
```

I really hope it will help somebody as it is really simple and requires almost no effort!

Answer (score 1):

You should check out HTML5 SVG (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp) and HTML5 Canvas (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp).

This is a lot of work though, you would be better off just using a library like flot or morris.

Comment: Thanks, that was quick! But I can't use a library because of the limitations posed by many web designing competitions and I want to be able to participate... I'm 13 and so I want to be able to compete.